# Does Kinesis expose any metrics/logs to detect the source for writes to Kinesis streams?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

If there are multiple write sources (external accounts) to my Kinesis stream, can I have any visibility on the bandwidth consumed by each writer? Any metrics/logs that I can look at?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT - I understand I can emit metrics during stream processing/consumption. I am curious to see if there are any logs/metrics provided by the platform itself.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs here (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/monitoring-with-cloudwatch.html) You can enable shard-level metrics (will incur additional Cloudwatch costs)

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong, but I don't see any metrics there that help with identifying data producers.

Comment: Do you need something more specific than shard-level `IncomingBytes`?

Comment: Yeah, I am more interested in the source, rather than the number of bytes received per shard. I guess I have no other choice but to emit them myself at the time of processing these records.

Comment: It does seem to give you the source though, as you have the `StreamName` dimension as long as you've enabled that level of metrics.